# fgets in fputs gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, fgets, fputs

I tried the following code and got a segmentation fault-

```
    int size=30;
    char *str;
    fputs(fgets(str,size,STDIN),STDOUT);
```

but when i run this as -

```
    buff=fgets(str,size,STDIN);
    fputs(buff,STDOUT);
```

it works just fine. Moreover the first code runs if i use malloc for str. I can't understand how this is happening.

Comment: I suspect the return of `fgets` uses an internal buffer (or maybe some compiler specific optimisation effect (magic)).  In your first case though you don't have any buffer since `str` is just a pointer not a buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
char *str;
// de-referenece str in ANY way.
```

You have a pointer which could be pointing *anywhere.* It is undefined behaviour to access arbitrary memory like that.

The fact that it works in one case but not the other is purely coincidental, you should be providing a proper buffer like:

```
char str[100]; // or whatever size you need.
```

or using `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory, as you've already discovered.

Once you get into the murky world of undefined behaviour, all bets are off.

It may crash, it may work, it may result in flying pigs or nasal demons or the collapse of your local space-time region into a singularity. Bottom line, don't do it :-)

Comment: i understand that but isn't `fputs(fgets(str,size,STDIN),STDOUT);`  &  `buff=fgets(str,size,STDIN);
    fputs(buff,STDOUT); ' the same thing?

Comment: Yes and no. They are both undefined behaviour but they may have different results, that's the whole point of UB. In fact, the exact same UB code is quite within its rights to don one thing today and a different thing tomorrow. At that point where you use UB, all bets are off, as per my last paragraph.

Comment: Where can i get to know the internal working? Suggestions, if any.Because i cant get much about this from manual pages. Thanks in advance